# Silverlight Child Window Parent Window

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expander

I have this issue: 
  - `OnButtonClick()` a child window is created. The parent window becomes `opaque`.

I need that the background, in this case the parent window, to be visible and have all the text readable.

I do not want it accessible or enabled in any way, but rather just to be able to see the text behind.

Any ideas? I have tried opaque, transparency, but none have worked to achieve the result I described above.

LATER EDIT:
   Thank you, but this solves half of my problem. 
   I've set the OverlayBrush to null and Overlay to 1. This way other components from the parent window are visible except one "Expander" which is 95% gray..

Do you have a clue why the expander has a different behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The child window control has dependency properties to modify the overlay brush and opacity: OverlayOpacity="1" OverlayBrush="Transparent", see here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070(v=vs.95).aspx